# parse xml file in python by xmltodict

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict

I am using xmltodict library in python (https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) to parse a xml file by:

```
import xmltodict
with open("MyXML.xml") as MyXML:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(MyXML.read())
```

The xml file looks good but I get this error:

```
ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

What should I do?

Comment: When you print `MyXML.read()`, what do you see?

Comment: where is MyXML defined?

Comment: When I print MyXML.read(), then I get nothing. But, when I open the xml file, then I can see the contents

Comment: Can you show us how you are reading the file in the code?

Comment: I have updated my post!

Comment: *The xml file looks good* is an assumption you should revisit.  If you want help, post an actual [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Please upload the xml doc

Answer (score 0):

In my uses of xmltodict, I have always parsed a string and to get an xml string is use etree. Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xmltodict

tree = ET.parse("MyXml.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
data = xmltodict.parse(ET.toString(root))
```

if you have your MyXml.xml file in a different locatin than this file you will need to handle that using **file** and the import os.

Good Luck, Hope this helps.